# Parse Apple plist with TSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, plist

I'm working with a SQL Server 2008 database that stores Apple plists in a column.  I'm looking for a quick and dirty way to extract some of that information.

I know [SQL Server can do XML parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669904/xml-parsing-with-sql-query). Since a plist isn't true XML, is there anything out there that can help me query/manipulate the data?

Alternatively, if anyone has a recommendation for a lightweight Java library to parse the plists, I could go that route too.

```
<dict>
  <key>BundleSize</key>
  <integer>16138240</integer>
  <key>DynamicSize</key>
  <integer>7569408</integer>
  <key>Identifier</key>
  <string>com.ea.scrabble.ipad.inc2</string>
  <key>Name</key>
  <string>Scrabble</string>
  <key>Version</key>
  <string>1.15.73</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: What DMBS are you using? There's some proprietary XML parsing tools in Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: Might give you some insight - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9207497/763026

Comment: What about plists isn't "true XML"?  As long as it is well-formed, you can stick it in an XML column and then use the information you've already referenced in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some basic TSQL string parsing if you just need to pull key/value pairs. You should be able to turn the code below into a function that will return a table of keys/values/types. Just paste this code and run it and you'll see what I mean. It will return a table with columns [ID], [Key], [Value], and [ValueType]. It's quick if you pass in a single plist.

```
DECLARE @pList VARCHAR(255)
SET @pList = 
'<dict> 

<key>BundleSize</key> 
<integer>16138240</integer> 

<key>DynamicSize</key> 
<integer>7569408</integer> 

<key>Identifier</key> 
<string>com.ea.scrabble.ipad.inc2</string> 

<key>Name</key> 
<string>Scrabble</string> 

<key>Version</key> 
<string>1.15.73</string> 

</dict> 
'

DECLARE @IsKey BIT
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @KeyValue TABLE (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Key] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [Value] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [ValueType] VARCHAR(255) NULL
    )

SET @IsKey = 1

WHILE LEN(@pList) > 10
BEGIN


    IF @IsKey = 1
    BEGIN

        -- Remove junk at the beginning of the string:
        SELECT @pList = SUBSTRING(@pList, CHARINDEX('<key>', @pList) + 5, LEN(@pList))

        -- Parse out the first value between the <key></key> tags:
        INSERT INTO @KeyValue ([Key])
            SELECT LEFT(@pList, CHARINDEX('</', @pList)-1)
        SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        -- Remove new junk at the beginning of the string:
        SELECT @pList = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@pList, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), @pList)+2, LEN(@pList)))

        SET @IsKey = 0

    END
    ELSE -- Is a value
    BEGIN

        -- Parse out the ValueType and Value:
        UPDATE @KeyValue
            SET ValueType = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@pList, 2, CHARINDEX('>', @pList)-2)),
            Value = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@pList, CHARINDEX('>', @pList)+1, CHARINDEX('</', @pList) - CHARINDEX('>', @pList)-1))
        WHERE ID = @ID

        -- Remove new junk at the beginning of the string:
        SELECT @pList = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@pList, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), @pList)+2, LEN(@pList)))

        SET @IsKey = 1

    END

END

SELECT *
FROM @KeyValue
```