# C# Deserialize XML into Object (with dictionary field)

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, dictionary, deserialization

How can I deserialize this XML to object?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>key1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>Name1</string>
        <key>price</key>
        <string>1000$</string>
        <key>count</key>
        <string>60</string>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>some description</string>
        <key>photoUrl</key>
        <string>http:/someurl</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>key2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>Name2</string>
        <key>price</key>
        <string>2000$</string>
        <key>count</key>
        <string>35</string>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>some description</string>
        <key>photoUrl</key>
        <string>http://someurl</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I think my object should have a dictionary as a field, but I have a problem to define appropriate class in code. How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/406235/A-Simple-PList-Parser-in-Csharp)?

Comment: What is about DataContractSerializer? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx

Comment: rene, no, it's not working. NotSupportedException.

Comment: Just a tip but I find its easier to do it the other way around. Serialize your object to generate the XML, then you can't accidently write a flawed XML structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Parsing .plist Files to plain XML C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014567/parsing-plist-files-to-plain-xml-c-sharp). The highest rated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9207497) (as of now) refers to a [C# project](https://github.com/animetrics/PlistCS) which supports both binary and xml plist formats. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to get the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to do the job.